# What possibilities are there to connect to a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, internet-connection

I was wondering: What possibilities are there to connect to a `postgres` database?

I know off top of my head that there are at least two possibilities.

1. The first possibility is a brute one: Open a port and let users anonymously make changes.
2. The second way is to create a website that communicates with postgres with use of SQL commands.

I couldn't find any more options on the internet so I was wondering if there are any. I'm curious if other options exist. Because maybe one of those options is the best solution to communicate with `postgres` via the internet.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's your end game here? It's generally considered very bad practice to make your database accessible from the internet.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do. You can have pgAdmin installed which will help you to access your database from web browser. Your user should have sufficient access to have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a networking/security type question, I think.

1. You can have your database fully exposed to the internet which is generally a bad idea unless you are just screwing around for fun and don't mind it being completely hosed at some point. I assume this is what you mean by option 1 of your question.
2. You can have a firewall in front that only exposes it for certain incoming IP's. This is a little better, but still feels a little exposed for a database, especially if there is sensitive data on it.
3. If you have a limited number of folks that need to interact with the DB, you can have it completely firewalled, but allow SSH connections to the internal network (possibly the same server) and then port forward through the ssh tunnel. This is  generally the best way if you need to give full DB access to folks that are external to the DB's network since SSH can be made much more secure than a direct DB connection by using a public/private keypair for each incoming connection. You can also only allow SSH from specific IP's through your firewall as an added level of security.
4. Similar to SSH, you could stand up a VPN and allow access to the LAN upon which the DB sits and control access through the VPN.
5. If you have a wider audience, you can allow no external access to the database (except for you or a DBA/Administrator type person through SSH tunneling or VPN). Then build access through a website where communication to the DB is done on the server side scripting (php, node.js, rails, .net, what-have-you). This is the usual website set up that every site with a database behind it uses. I assume that's what you mean in your option 2 of your question.

Comment: Never though that this question Will get answered. Thanks for explaining the different options.

Comment: @B.Termeer Yea... it's one of those "Not quite programming related so it's off topic for SO" and "Too broad so off topic for SO" and possibly an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where we people are asking for more info to properly answer it and a bit of reading between the lines. I would agree though that there really isn't any good info that I could find detailing the options. I'm certain there are more than 5, but these are definitely the most common. Worth answering for folks that may stumble across this in the future looking for direction.